# Is it possible to improve code by using variable padding to avoid cache contention?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I recently attended an interview where in a question was asked "Is it possible to improve the following code":

```
public class Performance{
    static class C1 {
        volatile long c1;
        volatile long c2;
    }

    static C1 p = new C1();

    static class Worker implements Runnable {

        private static final int INT = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 8;
        private final boolean b;

        Worker(boolean b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (b) {
                for (int i = 0; i < INT; i++) {
                    p.c1++;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < INT; i++) {
                    p.c2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(true));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker(false));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: You had your answer at the same time as you asked your question? You must be a really good programmer.

Comment: I didn't. I did a research afterwards.

Comment: your question: asked 11 mins ago, your answer: answered 11 mins ago

Comment: When you are looking for an answer, the best way is to find it by yourself.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg Answering your own question is one of the features on SO and there is nothing wrong with it...

Comment: @assylias I know, but already knowing the answer makes me think that it wasn't that problematic.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg What I meant is that when you ask a question, you can submit an answer at the same time. So if you are stuck on something and find an answer later on, it is perfectly fine to ask the question and answer it at the same time on SO for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @assylias I know, that it is a features of StackOverflow and that it is one of the features that makes this website better. But that doesn't have anything to do with the fact that the OP answered his question a few seconds after posting this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JIT compiler from java 7 is very smart. [It removes or reorders of unused field](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2011/08/false-sharing-java-7.html). For avoiding false sharing you should add `volatile` key word.

Java 8 has new annotation `@sun.misc.Contented`. See http://shipilev.net/talks/jvmls-July2013-contended.pdf for more details

Comment: The url to the annotation is broken

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have modified the link. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Padding variables *can* be an improvement, but since it is unknown (theoretically) on which platform your code eventually runs, you cannot be sure that padding will do the trick. There are processors that will gain a benefit from this, there are others that will slow down if you do.

This is such a deep micro-optimization that it is easy to break more than you fix. I would leave it to the JVM to decide how whether or not it wants to do that, unless this is an absolute must-have in a perfectly defined environment.

Btw. the most optimized version of that code above:

```
static class C1 {
    final long c1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE >>> 3;
    final long c2 = c2;
}
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

My answer was, yes it is possible by using variable padding to avoid cache contention. This technique presented in Java 8 LongAdder class.
**Padding is a strategy to reduce CPU cache contention by trying to make sure that different cells do not land in the same cache line.**

```
public class Performance{
    static class C1 {
        volatile long c1;
        long q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8;
        volatile long c2;
    }

    static C1 p = new C1();

    static class Worker implements Runnable {

        private static final int INT = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 8;
        private final boolean b;

        Worker(boolean b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (b) {
                for (int i = 0; i < INT; i++) {
                    p.c1++;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < INT; i++) {
                    p.c2++;
                }
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("took: " + (end - start) + " " + p.c1 + p.c2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(true));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker(false));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: For everyone who is confused by the answer: There is an article discussing this technique http://minddotout.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/java-8-concurrency-longadder/ . The padding has do be done two-sided.

Comment: I hope this wasn't your first answer, because I can see a lot more issues with that code that could be improved before trying to over-tune the JVM.

Comment: Removing the `volatile` keyword as the threads don’t really share the variables would have been a lot easier…